# Get the list of posted messages of the current user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show the **list of posts** that **the current user** has posted. 
This is what I got. I need to get the get the **uid from the users structure**. Then i need to check of the uid from the users structure **the same is as posts/uid**. That is what i don't know how to do because i don't know **how you can get in a posts that had id for example: "-Kvs50Et17ilfzdgdhcK"**. it need somehow to check all the posts that have been placed and than check of the **uid from the users the same is as the uid of the posts**. Please help!

```
    var Gametext: String = ""
    var Consoletext: String = ""

    var dataBaseRef: DatabaseReference! {
        return Database.database().reference()
    }

    var post: Post! {
        didSet {

            let postsRef = dataBaseRef.child("posts/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
        let userQuery = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        userQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Game").value as? String)
            print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Console").value as? String)
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


        }
    }
```

Here is my post structure:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-Kvs50Et17ilfzdgdhcK" : {
      "Console" : "Xbox One",
      "ExtraInfo" : "Test",
      "Game" : "test",
      "Gamertag" : "test1244@gamertag",
      "photoURL" : "",
      "postDate" : 1.5074008811834E9,
      "postId" : "C835A03A-9BAF-423E-87F0-60139DA893EB",
      "uid" : "7E4vEew5RbMsWmSMijZxT4TzxHh1",
      "username" : "dani Kemper"
    }
  },
```

Here is my user structure:

```
    "users" : {
        "7E4vEew5RbMsWmSMijZxT4TzxHh1" : {
          "Console" : "Xbox One",
          "Gamertag" : "test1244@gamertag",
          "country" : "Antigua & Barbuda",
          "email" : "dani@gmail.com",
          "photoURL" : "",
          "uid" : "7E4vEew5RbMsWmSMijZxT4TzxHh1",
          "username" : "dani Kemper"
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're reading `/posts/7E4vEew5RbMsWmSMijZxT4TzxHh1` in the database. That's not where the posts for the users are, so your completion handler is called with a snapshot without data. Since you then try to read data from it, the code fails.

You will need to read the data from the database with a query that check the `uid` property of each post:

```
let postsRef = dataBaseRef.child("posts/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
let userQuery = postsRef.queryOrder(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
userQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Game").value as? String)
    print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Console").value as? String)
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I recommend reading up on [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). A few hours spent reading and studying those code samples, will save a lot of time and questions down the line.

Comment: Have got a error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSEnumerator' on line: print(snapshot.children("Game").value as? String)

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: @Danjhi it says in the answer `snapshot.child("Game")`, not `.children`

Comment: I know but if i do `snapshot.child("Game")` than the error is: `Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'child' `

Comment: I keep forgetting that `DataSnapshot` doesn't have a `child` method. I updated the code to use `childSnapshot(forPath:`

Comment: Hello Frank, i updated my question because the explanation of the first question wasn't verry clear. I tried to explain it as good as i can with my English. Can you please look at the new question? Thanks!